# Animate UIView — objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

I have a UIButton, and when it's pressed a UIView expands down from the button. The view is first set to:

```
CGRectMake(0, (button.frame.orgin.y+button.frame.size.hight), self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
```

Then when the button is pressed the hight expands:

```
CGRectMake(0, (button.frame.orgin.y+button.frame.size.hight), self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
```

When the view is expanded and the button is pressed again the view is collapsed again into a height of 0. I have animated everything of this with `[UIView beginAnimation:nil context:NULL]...;` Not with a specified animationTransition or curve.

My problem is that the animation isn't what I want. It like becomes tinier and tinier during the animation, which does make sense since the height is changed.

My question is how I can change the animation and make the view look like it travels up behind the button, without being pushed together. — this when it's pressed the second time to collapse.

Please ask if the question is unclear
Thanks!

Comment: So actually what you want is not for the height to change, but only for the view to travel vertically?

Comment: And you really want to be using block based animation not `beginAnimation`, `commitAnimation`.

Comment: @verbumdei yes kind of

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to animate the `y` origin of the frame and keep the height the same before and after animation. Just change your first code (the one before animation) to:

```
CGRectMake(0, button.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
```

Or if you want to make use of CGRect methods:

```
CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMinY(button.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 200);
```

And see if this will give you the result you want.

It is also good to use the animateWithDuration block-based method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(button.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 200);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks but my button is just 50 heigh so the view doesn't "fit" behind it

Comment: Then you need to decide what you want to do with the height difference. Maybe you want to animate the opacity change too from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: yes but I have other buttons that are positioned relatively to that view